# How to handle long tag names

Tags: discussion, tags

In a recent (rather whimsical) question, I used the tags [igo](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/igo) and [esc](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esc), because the full spellings (Intergovernmental organization and Eurovision Song Contest) would be too long.

Are such acronyms suitable as tag names, or should the maximum tag length be increased?

Comment: Do people recognize 'esc' as 'Eurovision Song Contest'?  Do you even need a tag for eurovision song contest?

Comment: @SamIam - I've removed that tag from the question as part of my edit to focus it on the actual political question.

Comment: I would probably say "Eurovision" is both a shorter and more recognisable tag name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good rule of thumb for using abbreviations in your tags is to use them if you think that people who see your tag will be able to tell what it is without extra context.  If not, than it's not a particularly strong tag.

according to wikipedia, there are a lot of things that have an abbreviation of `ESC`
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esc

But if you go to the [Eurovision Song Contest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest) page, the first thing it says is:

> "Eurovision" redirects here. For other uses, see Eurovision (disambiguation).

so `Eurovision` might be an even better tag.

---

Also, I don't know if `Eurovision song contest` really needs a tag.  It doesn't really sound like a catagory of question.  It kinda feels like the [foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreach)  tag on StackOverflow.